# Weight based round robin pattern

Tags: java

I'm trying to write in Java a simple algorithm to select which server needs to execute one operation. I want to use a sort of round robin but with a weight on each server. So far I have coded the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Weight for each server
    int x = 1;
    int y = 3;

    int counterx = 0;
    int countery = 0;

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
        counterx++;
        countery++;
        if (counterx == x) {
            System.out.println("Chosen x ");
            counterx = 0;
        }
        if (countery == y) {
            System.out.println("Chosen y ");
            countery = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

So given two servers, x and y, I have stored the weight to assign to each server in the x and y variable and a counter for each server as well. This seems to work, however in case the number of servers will grow the code will become utterly more complex. Is there any util package which can help me to determine the server to invoke based on a weight factor ? 
Thanks

Comment: I would consider using a random number generator. e.g. generate a random number between 0 - 99. Then decide what to do with it based on where it falls. e.g. if you want to use server x 75% of the time if the random number is between 25 and 99 choose server x else server y.

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of the algorithm. You mean that a server with a greater weight should be chosen more often? In your code, both `x` and `y` will be chosen on some iterations, and none of them would be chosen on other iterations if the weight of `x` weren't 1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it happens types implementing [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#ceilingEntry(K)) are ideal for this, such as `TreeMap`.

You need to do something like:

1. Encapsulate your server details (name, address, selection weight)
2. Store a list of servers (which you can then later add to/delete from)
3. Select a random number between 0 and the sum of all the weights.
4. Search the server list for the first server for which the sum of weights for all servers up to and including this server is more than the random value.

In this way ordering of the servers in the list won't matter. This is exactly what `NavigableMap`, used with the `ceilingEntry` method does.

For example:

```
public class ServerDetails {
    int weight;
    String address;
    public Server(int weight, String address) { 
        this.weight = weight;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getWeight(){return this.weight;}
    public String getAddress(){return this.address;}
}
```

You then define a pool of servers using something like:

```
public class ServerPool {
    Random someRandGen = new Random();
    TreeMap<Integer, ServerDetails> pool;
    int totalWeight;

    public void init(ArrayList<ServerDetails> servers) {
        this.pool = new TreeMap<Integer, ServerDetails>();
        // create the "weighted selection" list
        totalWeight = 0;
        for(ServerDetails s : servers) {
            //  associate each server with the sum of the weights so far
            totalWeight += s.getWeight();
            this.pool.put(totalWeight, s);
        }
    }

    public ServerDetails getNext() {
        int rnd = someRandGen.nextInt(this.totalWeight);
        return pool.ceilingEntry(rnd).getValue();
    }
}
```

You can then define add/remove methods for the pool accordingly. Used with the below example code, the % of times each was chosen were:

```
a: 11.1%
b: 40.8%
c: 19.6%
d: 28.5%
```

Code:

```
ArrayList<ServerDetails> servers = new ArrayList<ServerDetails>(){{
    add(new ServerDetails(10, "a"));
    add(new ServerDetails(40, "b"));
    add(new ServerDetails(20, "c"));
    add(new ServerDetails(30, "d"));
}}; 

ServerPool serverPool = new ServerPool();
serverPool.init(servers);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    System.out.println(serverPool.getNext().getAddress());
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with java. But what is the algorithm of choosing A||B||C||D server? `[a: 11.1%, b: 40.8%, c: 19.6%,d: 28.5%]`
Each request have own id [1..N]; How to calculate which server must take a request?

Comment: @LINKeRxUA and easy way to handling the "choosing" is to create an array with an entry for each percent, then randomly choose a number up to the length of the array. Using your example, I may have an array with `["a", "a", "a", ... 11 times, "b", "b", "b" ... 41 times, "c", "c", "c" ... 20 times, "d", "d", "d", ... 29 times]. The length of the array is 101. I choose a random integer between 0 and 100, representing an index of one of the records. Given the quantity of entries, each has their own respective odds of being "chosen".

Comment: @LINKeRxUA the proposed solution by @Andy above leverages a data structure in Java called TreeMap. If you read up on it, it sorts each entry by it's key. What he did is simply used the weight as the key, and the server (with its address, etc.) as the value. If you have weights 10, 40, 20, 30 for example, you add them all up to 100. You then choose a random integer between 1 and 100 and let's assume it's 6. He uses the `ceilingEntry(rnd)` method to find matching key in TreeMap whose range contains that random number. Then returns it. Similar to my array method above, you have same odds.